# How to Display String Value to UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
//array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath =  [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"first.database"];
NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
NSFileManager *fn=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL success=[fn fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"first.database"];
    success = [fn copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
}


const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT firstname FROM second"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            arrival = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];


       NSLog(@"Result %@",arrival);


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

In this Example i want to display "arrival" value to UITableView... Anyone Help me

Answer (score 1):

First of all - use FMDB wrapper for sqlite databases. It makes life so much easier! (check their [GitHub here](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) and [this tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/))
Second - if you want to assign result of SELECT to cell just use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = your_result;
```

in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Standard UITableViewCell has two UILabels: cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLabel. Where do you want to display your value and what's type it is?

Comment: Just assign 'arrival' to cell.textLabel.text. UILabel text property is NSString, so converting this value is not needed. cell.textLabel.text = arrival; should do the job.

Comment: NSLog(@"Result %@",arrival); in your code.Is it giving you desired result?

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NULL];
    cell.textLabel.text=arrival;
    return cell;
}
```